# Не подключается js файл к html

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с очень странной для меня ситуацией: подключил js файл с обработчиками ajax к файлу index.html, на ПК полностью работает всё, а вот захожу с телефона и не работает. Проверял на поддержку скрипта, вставлял js-код из файла напрямую в index.html - всё работает как на телефоне, так и на ПК.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/obrphp.js"></script>
```

Это код подключения js файла, который размещен внутри `<head>` в index.html.

Подскажите пожалуйста, с чем может связана данная проблема?

Проблема в этом коде:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => { //Поиск людей
  document.querySelector('#txtsearchobch').addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if('key' in e) {
      if(e.key.toLowerCase() !== 'enter') {
        return;
      }
    } else {
      if(e.keyCode !== 13) {
        return;
      }
    }
      var txtsearchobch = $("#txtsearchobch").val();
      window.location.replace('?search='+ txtsearchobch +'#searchus');

  });
});
```

Comment: Если найдется желание повозиться, можете попробовать вот эту штучку http://vorlonjs.com/.
А вообще, смущает, что используется `type="text/javascript"`. Если `doctype html5`, то стоит убрать тип, но, сомневаюсь что проблема в этом. И конечно же, проблема может быть в самом телефоне, в браузере, который используется и т.д.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын проблема находиться в самой первой строке кода

Comment: @СашаОсипов  уверены что стрелочная функция поддерживается?

Comment: я вижу проблему: `e => {` синтаксис, который весьма слабо поддерживается. если у вас нет библиотек трансформации - нужно переписать.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын согласен, `babel` не зря писали.

Comment: Вот именно из-за неё видимо и не работает, так как я удалил "DOMContentLoaded" и всё равно не отображает на мобильном а как удалил "'DOMContentLoaded', e =>", так всё заработало...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему, проблема в использовании нового синтаксиса из стандарта ECMAScript 6, а именно - "стрелочные функции" (arrow functions):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => { //Поиск людей
    ...
});
```

Лучше использовать кроссбраузерный вариант

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e){ //Поиск людей
    ...
});
```

Подробную таблицу с описанием **поддержки стандарта ECMAScript 6** для браузеров и платформ можно найти здесь: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Если хочется пользоваться именно новым синтаксисом - нужно использовать один из доступных **компиляторов из ES6 в ES5** ([traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler),[babel](https://babeljs.io/)).

Comment: Огромное спасибо, а то я уже замучался с этим)